# responsive menu doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive

i'm writting a web for a school project. It must be in HTML5, css and responsive. So that i found a responsive menu that I implement. In the index it works correctly but in the second page it doesn't work, onClick dooesnt show the menu. I've been looking but i dont found anything to solve it.

This is the code of the second page if anyone wants the code of Index I could update it with this.

This is the html page

https://codeshare.io/5MjQPq

And this two are the css pages

https://codeshare.io/2BM0Bd

If anyone want see the index or the complet project I can send or upload it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTMl, on the section you have the unit of the click on the menu link (#pull) you forgot the $(document).ready

So instead of your part

```
$(function().....
```

you need to have

```
$(document).ready(function()......
```

Did you noticed the change in the code share page in the line 35?

Comment: Thanks! yes i see the change, I'm going to test it! ;)